# Prove that $R^n \backslash C$ is connected for $n\geq 2$ and that it's simply connected if $n\geq 3$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $C$ be a compact subset of $R^n$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite number of open balls $\{B_i\}$ that covers $C$ and $\sum_i r_i\leq \epsilon$, where $r_i$ is the radius of $B_i$. Prove that $R^n \backslash C$ is connected for $n\geq 2$ and that it's simply connected if $n\geq 3$.

Comment: What is the number $r_i$?

Comment: $r_i$ is the radius of $B_i$.

Answer (score 1):

hint: prove first that C is totally disconnected, then try to prove directly or make use of Alexander duality theorem.

Comment: Alexander duality will not suffice to establish simple connectivity. Otherwise, it is a good hint.

Comment: Can I do it without Alexander duality theorem?

Comment: The connectivity case $n\geq2$ follows directly from the classical Kuratowski
theorem, implying that if $M\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\dim M\leq n-2$, then
$\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash M$ is connected. Now, as $C$ is totally
disconnected, $\dim C=0$ and we are done.

Comment: @simeon: Do you mean the Kuratowski theorem on planar graphs. I don't find the relation with that.